# Change form data from square notation to dot notation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework

When I am doing ajax I am sending some data in json format
    But I can see in chrome tools -> network XHR that the form parameters are in square brackets way

```
Ex:
source[title]:xxxxxxxxxxxx
source[thumbnail]:xxxxxxxxxxx
source[keywords]:xxxxxxxxx
source[type]:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
source[url]:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

But I want the form data which I send to backend to be in this way

Ex:
source.title:xxxxxxxxxxxx  
source.thumbnail:xxxxxxxxxx  
source.keywords:xxxxxxxxxxx  
source.type:xxxxxxxxxxxx  
source.url:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  

My Backend is Play Framework  
I am using jquery 2.2.4
```

Answer (score -1):

Square bracket and dot notation are parts of *JavaScript* syntax, they have nothing to do with JSON strings.

Square bracket notation is for when you want to access a property value in JS dynamically with a string based key, e.g.:

```
source["title"] = "xxxxx"
```

Dot notation is for when you know the key and use it directly:

```
source.title = "xxxxx"
```

It doesn't matter whether you used square bracket or dot notation to build your object in JavaScript, when its converted to a JSON string to send over the network it will look the same:

```
'{"title":"xxxxx"}'
```